# how to host angularjs with django, django-tastypie as backend?

Tags: django, angularjs

I am building a site using angularjs. The backend is django and django-tastypie.

currently we hosted the frontend stuffs(`angularjs`) in a seperate domain(different from django domain).

> we seperated all angularjs htmls from django

it is the correct way?

i found some others were rendered the angularjs templates through django views.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWJorwEQWLk (which uses django rest framework, but the principles are the same). Normally, you should not use different domains to host angularjs and django (this will complicate sessions handling, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the *correct * way necessarily, but separating Django and Angular templates is certainly a very sensible thing to do. From the Django point of view, Angular templates are just static files.

What I've done in the past is to have a single base Django view that includes a few js variables set from template vars, then served the rest of the Angular stuff via static files and ajax.